# How can I implement something like Destiny's public events?

Tags: architecture, networking, multiplayer

Bungie has shown a gameplay trailer for their new game, Destiny. The part that really stood out for me was the 'public events' that can happen randomly while playing. Now I've thought about it for a while but I can't figure out how I might implement a feature like this.

Perhaps a dedicated event server that all game servers (or all clients) must connect to?

Answer (score 1):

I think a few games have done something similar (Warhammer online is the first that comes to mind). I believe how it has been done in the past is that players are put on a world server like any other MMO (or play locally, or with P2P) but when they enter a certain zone they are all transferred to the same server temporarily (or a specialised server) and put back when they exit the zone.